# How to transform $ax^2+bx+c$ into $p(x-h)^2 +k$?

Tags: quadratic-forms

How to transform $ax^2+bx+c$ into $p(x-h)^2 +k$?

For example, if I have this form: $$8x^2+3x+5$$, how can render it in the $p(x-h)^2 +k$ format?

Comment: If I were you, I would try to develop $p(x-h)^2 +k)$, and then identify coefficients. What does it give ?

Comment: It's called Completing the square: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square

Comment: Factor the leading coefficient into everything, then completing the squares.

Comment: What have you tried? And what exactly is the context behind your question? As is, the question does not meet the guidelines for quality of the forum.

Comment: Have a look at this in Khan Academy https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratic-functions-equations#x2f8bb11595b61c86:more-on-completing-square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user **Deepak** mentioned:
$$
h=-\frac{b}{2a}=-\frac{3}{16},\quad{k}=\left(c-\frac{b^{2}}{4a}\right)=\frac{151}{32},\implies{8}\left(x+\frac{3}{16}\right)^{2}+\frac{151}{32}=8x^2+3x+5.
$$